# HTML/CSS Footer division into columns

Tags: html, css, layout, responsive-design

I'm designing a website, and I'm currently trying to do the part regarding the footer. So far I haven't had any troubles, till I decided to do the footer layout.

To be precise: **I want to divide the footer into three separate columns as shown on the image below:**

[image: design]

Yet the outcome is this:

[image: outcome]

As you can see, the footer column does not hold it's width and just stretches to the content. For different settings other things happened, but it never appeared proper to me.

My current, **non working** approach:

## HTML

```
<html>

<!-- BEGIN HEAD -->
<head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />

    <!-- Start WOWSlider.com HEAD section -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="engine0/style.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="engine0/jquery.js"></script>
    <!-- End WOWSlider.com HEAD section -->

</head>
<!-- END HEAD -->

<!-- BEGIN BODY -->
<body>

    <!-- BEGIN WRAPPER FOR FOOTER PUSHING -->
    <div class="wrapper">

    <!-- BEGIN .PAGE -->
    <div class="page">

        <!-- BEGIN .LOGO -->
        <div class="logo"> 

            <img class="logoBB" src="images/logo.png">
            <br><text class="logosub">Tworzymy Dla Ciebie</text></br>

        </div>
        <!-- END .LOGO -->

        <!-- BEGIN .MENU -->
        <div class="menu">

            <hr class="top_line">

                <ul>
                <li><a href="#">O NAS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">GALERIA PRODUKTÓW</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">AKTUALNOŚCI</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">ZADAJ PYTANIE</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">KONTAKT</a></li>
                </ul>

            <hr class="bottom_line">


        </div>
        <!-- END .MENU -->          

        <!-- Start WOWSlider.com BODY section --> <!-- add to the <body> of your page -->
        <div id="wowslider-container0">
        <div class="ws_images"><ul>
            <li><img src="data0/images/slide1.png" alt="http://wowslider.net/" title="WOOD" id="wows0_0"/></li>
            <li><img src="data0/images/3025992posterpdesignwork.jpg" alt="CUBES" title="CUBES" id="wows0_1"/></li>
        </ul></div>
        <div class="ws_bullets"><div>
            <a href="#" title="WOOD"><span><img src="data0/tooltips/slide1.png" alt="WOOD"/>1</span></a>
            <a href="#" title="CUBES"><span><img src="data0/tooltips/3025992posterpdesignwork.jpg" alt="CUBES"/>2</span></a>
        </div></div><div class="ws_script" style="position:absolute;left:-99%"><a href="http://wowslider.com">wowslider.com</a> by WOWSlider.com v8.6</div>
        <div class="ws_shadow"></div>
        </div>  
        <script type="text/javascript" src="engine0/wowslider.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="engine0/script.js"></script>
        <!-- End WOWSlider.com BODY section --> 

        </div>
        <!-- END .PAGE -->

        <!-- FOOTER PUSHER -->
        <div class="push"></div>

    </div>
    <!-- END .WRAPPER -->

    <!-- BEGIN FOOTER -->
    <div class="footer">

        <!-- BEGIN FOOTER CONTAINER -->
        <div class="footer_container">

            <!-- BEGIN .FINDUS -->
            <div class="findus">

            </div>
            <!-- END .FINDUS -->

            <!-- BEGIN .DESIGNERS -->
            <div class="designers">

            </div>
            <!-- END .DESIGNERS -->

            <!-- BEGIN .INSPIRATIONS -->
            <div class="inspirations">

            </div>
             <!-- END .INSPIRATIONS -->

        </div>
        <!-- END FOOTER CONTAINER -->       

    </div>
    <!-- END FOOTER -->

</body>
<!-- END BODY -->
```

## CSS

```
/* GENERAL PAGE SETTINGS */
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.page {
    margin: 25px auto;
    width: 960px;
}

/* WRAPPER & HTML SETTINGS */
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -168px; 
}
.footer, .push {
    height: 168px; /* .push must be the same height as .footer */
}

/* FOOTER SETTINGS */
.footer {
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #323232;
}

.footer_container {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: red;
}

.footer .findus {
    float: left;
    width: 33,33333%;
}

.footer .designers {
    float: left;
    width: 33,33333%;
    background-color: red;
}


.footer .inspirations {
    float: left;
    width: 33,33333%;
}


/* LOGO SETTINGS */

img.logoBB {
    margin: 0 28.95833333333333%;

}

.logosub {
    font-family: Federant;
    font-size: 17.83px;
    color: #94979b;
    padding: 0 40.625%;
}

/* MENU SETTINGS */
.menu {
    margin: 0 90px;
}


.menu ul {
    text-align: center;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 17px auto;
}

.menu li {
    display: inline-block;
}

.menu a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: slabo;
    font-size: 18px;    
}

.menu .top_line {
    width: 780px;
    margin: 32px 0 0;
    height: 2px;
    color: black;
    background-color: black;
}

.menu .bottom_line {
    width: 780px;
    margin: 0 0 40px;
    height: 3px;
    color: black;
    background-color: black;
}
```

### What I have tried (none worked):

- Applying table to a footer
- Using left, right and center float (in that order) with both % values and pixel values
- Tried fixed values of everything in footer (this worked) yet I'm aiming to make this website responsive so that is not the way to go by any means.

If you happen to notice any other mistakes I have made, I'd be grateful for pointing them out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your footer columns need to have `position: relative` for them to become columns. Also, you have commas in your width percentages that need to be decimals. So each footer css would be as follows (with their correct class names, of course--I just grabbed one as an example):

```
.footer .inspirations {
    float: left;
    width: 33.33333%;
    position: relative;
}
```

[See Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jbyKOq)

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
.findus, .designers, .inspirations{
   display:inline-block;
   position:relative;
   width:calc(100% / 3);
}
```

Also, your three footer divs are inside the .footer_contatiner div, which has a max-width set to it. Put them outside the wrapper if you want it to extend 100% of the page width.

Comment: the .footer_container is inside the footer exactly for that reason. I want the footer bg to extend to full page, but i want its content to sit in the above pages' boundary.

Comment: Ah, well then I would use the answer that was posted above using float and position:relative

Answer (score 0):

Try using inline / inline-block. You'd just change a few lines in the container and in each column:

```
.footer_container {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: red;
    display: inline;
}

.footer .findus {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 33,33333%;
}

.footer .designers {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 33,33333%;
    background-color: red;
}


.footer .inspirations {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 33,33333%;
}
```